# Azure ARM template dynamic variable binding

Tags: azure, templates, variables, dynamic, azure-resource-manager

How do I get the value of a key from a list by passing a dynamic variable?

**My Code**

```
    "variables": {
                "locationCodeList": [
                  {
                    "southcentralus": "ussc",
                    "northcentralus": "usnc",
                    "westcentralus": "uswc",
                    "centralus": "usce",
                    "westus": "uswe",
                    "westus2": "usw2"
                  }
                ],
                "locCode": "[variables('locationCodeList')[0].(resourceGroup().location)]"
}
```

I want to get the value **ussc** when the resourceGroup().location is **southcentralus**. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its json so you can just use []

I used this command to test the template below.
az deployment group create --resource-group rg-test --template-file .\blank.template

Update to make locationCodeList an object instead of an array.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  },
  "variables": {
                "locationCodeList": {
                    "southcentralus": "ussc",
                    "northcentralus": "usnc",
                    "westcentralus": "uswc",
                    "centralus": "usce",
                    "westus": "uswe",
                    "westus2": "usw2"
                  },
                "locCode": "[variables('locationCodeList')[resourceGroup().location]]"
},
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "locCodeOutput": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('locCode')]"
    }
  }
}
```

In case there was a need for this I wanted to leave it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  },
  "variables": {
                "locationCodeList": [
                  {
                    "southcentralus": "ussc",
                    "northcentralus": "usnc",
                    "westcentralus": "uswc",
                    "centralus": "usce",
                    "westus": "uswe",
                    "westus2": "usw2"
                  }
                ],
                "locCode": "[variables('locationCodeList')[0][resourceGroup().location]]"
},
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "locCodeOutput": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('locCode')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that for simple object property reference you don't need the [0] - you can remove that and the [] in the var definition - here's a similar example: https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/blob/master/paired-region/azuredeploy.json

Comment: True, could update the variable so instead of an array it was just a JSON object.  Thanks for that callout I have updated my answer to reflect that, and I should have done it.